# asp.net web application for automatically deploying code from subversion

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, svn

I hope this isn't a stupid question, but after searching around for quite a while, I haven't been able to find anything quite like what I'm trying to do:

We build a series of web applications that are based on a common asp.net mvc engine. I would like to write a .net web app that would allow our project managers to automatically check out the most recent stable version from subversion, build it, and then deploy it to the server, so they could then begin to customize it. Has anyone here built anything like that before?

Since the web app needs to be responsible for some other functions, it makes more sense to me to find existing code (or an example) that is doing something like this, rather than using an off-the-shelf package.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a few [CruiseControl.Net](http://confluence.public.thoughtworks.org/display/CCNET/) tasks - a couple of them hook to batch files on the server that call out to MSBuild to build, clean up and deploy + zip up the web application on the build machine.

This way I can make builds for QA and other departments.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to shell out to svn.exe for the checkout you could use [SVN.NET](http://www.pumacode.org/projects/svndotnet/) to access the repository from your code.

Answer (score 0):

If you use TortoiseSVN, you can make use of its [client-side hooks](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-settings.html#tsvn-dug-settings-hooks) to run a script (e.g., a .BAT file) after checkout that would build your solution, and then copy it to a target directory.